# selecting last non zero variable from array

Tags: sas

I have some array step [10] step1-step10
my example data set(1 row):

```
___________________________
step1 step2 step3 step4 etc
la    la2   lala
```

I need do create new variable which will costist from last non zero variable.
In my example it will be   newvariable = lala

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the array and assign `newvar` the non-blank values.  You will always assign it the final time on the last non-blank value.

```
data want;
set have;
array step[10] step1-step10;

do i=1 to 10;
   if strip(step[i]) ^= "" then
      newvar = step[i];
end;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you very much